# Is it grammatically correct to use "be" in this context

Tags: future-tense

I want to say "happy new year" to my old professor.

I wrote this:

> Dear Ms. XXX
>
> I hope next year **be** full of success and happiness with great health for you.

Is "be" correct here?

Comment: *I hope the next year will be ...*

Comment: "**May** next year be full of success and happiness..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. it's not correct.
You can say wish you full of success, great happiness and health next year

Comment: "wish you full of ..." is not correct, though you could say something like "I wish you a year full of success, great happiness and health."

Answer (score 1):

As "next year" is in the future, you need to use the future tense. "I hope next year WILL BE full of success and happiness for you."

"Be" is almost always used as part of "will be" (future), "to be" (infinitive), "can be" or "may be" (conditionals).

You could also say, "I wish you success and happiness next year", no doubt many other variations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the structure consistent by saying, "I hope the new year will be full of success, happiness and good health for you."

"Great health" is correct, but sounds awkward unless the person was suffering from a severe illness and you are hoping they recover. Stick to "good" if you're just trying to be polite and friendly.

"Next year" is also corect, but tends to refer to a specific event: "Let's get together again next year." If you're just making a general statement about the upcoming year, it's better to say "new year."